See number of users connected to a Spring Boot and Tomcat application
Is it possible to get the number of users connected to an application with an off-board Tomcat?
I tried to use netstat -ano to see the process.
Also I tried ps -ef | grep java but it gave me info that I'm not sure is correct.

duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385737/how-to-know-how-many-connections-are-connecting-with-springboot-website

Several options:
1. Check the number of active sessions in Tomcat Manager:

Go to tomcat manager page (e.g. http://localhost:8080/manager/html)
Log in and you will the info regarding number of active sessions


2. Use netstat
netstat -an | grep 8080 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l

You could also try to see it in java code - see here
